# How to draw a cubic Bézier curve in wxWidgets?

Tags: qt, wxwidgets

In Qt, the cubic Bézier curve can be drawn using the following codes.

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(80, 320);
path.cubicTo(200, 80, 320, 80, 480, 320);

painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 8));
painter.drawPath(path);
```

How to draw the same curve using wxWidgets?

Comment: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/classwx_graphics_path.html

Comment: Wonderful. Perhaps you can make it into an answer. Just show the wxWidgets equivalent in it. Then you have a nice Question/Answer pair.

Comment: can't you use splines? wxDC has a function to draw splines.

Comment: @allenchen While this is a few years old, it would be great if you could post an answer on how you solved this and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at wxGraphicsPath::AddQuadCurveToPoint.